# Rubocop "unexpected token tCOLON" error in yml files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, lint, rubocop

When running Rubocop I get this error for all yml files under config folder.

example:

```
config/database.yml:1:8: E: unexpected token tCOLON
(Using Ruby 2.1 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
default: &default
       ^
config/database.yml:2:10: E: unexpected token tCOLON
(Using Ruby 2.1 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
  adapter: postgresql
         ^
config/database.yml:3:11: E: unexpected token tCOLON
(Using Ruby 2.1 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
  encoding: unicode
          ^
config/database.yml:4:7: E: unexpected token tCOLON
(Using Ruby 2.1 parser; configure using TargetRubyVersion parameter, under AllCops)
  pool: 5
      ^
```

This is my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: otimicar_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: otimicar_test
```

What does it means? Other files likes secrets.yml are generating the same kind of error also...

Comment: rubocop is supposed to ignore .yml files. What is the output of `rubocop -L`?

Comment: I was doing it wrong. Im running rubocop folder by folder so it would be easier to fix the offenses. So, I was running `rubocop config/*`, then I realized that this command would force rubocop to scan all files inside the folder. The correct command is `rubocop config/`, without the '*' 